# How to transpose an Apache Spark Dataset in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, pivot, transpose, apache-spark-dataset

I have an Apache Spark `Dataset<Row>` which I want to transpose. From some topics here it is clear for me that this can be done by grouping-pivoting-aggregation. Yet I don't get it in the way I need. I have following input table:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| rho_0 | rho_1| rho_2|rho_3 | names|
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|  1    | 0.89 | 0.66 | 0.074|  rho |
|  1    | 0.89 | 0.66 | 0.074|absRho|
|  0    |  1   | 2    |  3   | lag  |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

What I need is

```
+-------+------+------+
| rho   |absRho| lag  |
+-------+------+------+
|  1    | 1    |  0   |
|  0.89 | 0.89 |  1   |
|  0.66 | 0.66 |  2   |
|  0.074| 0.074|  3   |
+-------+------+------+
```

I tried something like

```java
Dataset<Row> transposed = coll.groupBy().pivot("names").min("rho_0");
```

but this doesn't work. Calling `groupBy` with a sequence of columns from the input also doesn't work. I found a workaround, which I don't like:

```java
Dataset<Row> transposed = coll.groupBy().pivot("names").min("rho_0")
for (int i = 1; i < nlags; i++) {
    transposed = transposed.union(coll.groupBy().pivot("names").min("rho_" + i));
}
```

but its really slow and its not meant to be implemented in that way. Do you have some advices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered in scala because it's easier to test (with the REPL). You should have the basic idea. Let me know if you need help translating it to java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built in function in spark to do that. There is a solution using `pivot`, but you need to "explode" the dataframe before. It should be much faster than your solution based on unions.

In scala, it would go as follows. I added a java version right below.

```scala
// scala
val cols = df.columns
  .filter(_ != "names")
  .map(n => struct(lit(n) as "c", col(n) as "v"))
val exploded_df = df.select(col("names"), explode(array(cols : _*)))
```

```java
// java
Column[] cols = Arrays
    .stream(df.columns())
    .filter(x -> ! x.equals("names"))
    .map(n -> struct(lit(n).alias("c"), col(n).alias("v")))
    .toArray(Column[]::new);
Dataset<Row> exploded_df = df.select(col("names"), explode(array(cols)));
```

```scala
exploded_df.show();
+------+-------------+
| names|          col|
+------+-------------+
|   rho|    [rho_0,1]|
|   rho| [rho_1,0.89]|
|   rho| [rho_2,0.66]|
|   rho|[rho_3,0.074]|
|absRho|    [rho_0,1]|
|absRho| [rho_1,0.89]|
|absRho| [rho_2,0.66]|
|absRho|[rho_3,0.074]|
|   lag|    [rho_0,0]|
|   lag|    [rho_1,1]|
|   lag|    [rho_2,2]|
|   lag|    [rho_3,3]|
+------+-------------+
```

Basically, I built an array column that contains structs composed of the name of the column and its value. Then, I used the explode function to flatten this array. From there, we can use `pivot` as usual ;-)

```scala
// scala and java
exploded_df
  .groupBy(col("col.c"))
  .pivot("names")
  .agg(first(col("col.v")))
  .orderBy("c")
  .show();
+-----+------+---+-----+
|    c|absRho|lag|  rho|
+-----+------+---+-----+
|rho_0|     1|  0|    1|
|rho_1|  0.89|  1| 0.89|
|rho_2|  0.66|  2| 0.66|
|rho_3| 0.074|  3|0.074|
+-----+------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Is `df.columns` a sequence of columns or column names? and what does the `map` function excatly do? Java's `map` takes 2 arguments: `Function<Row,Object>` and an `Encoder<Object>`.

Comment: I've made the code more readable and added a java version. `map` is just a function that associates (or maps) a value to each value of a collection. In java, you can achieve similar things with streams. There's just a little bit more boilerplate.

Comment: thanks a lot! and thanks for splitting this in 2 steps and explaining. now I get, what is the idea behind exploding.